# Why is this search form not submitting when button is clicked?

Tags: search, forms

I've got a search form on my page, which works perfectly fine when I enter the text and press enter, however it doesn't submit anything when `.submit-search` button is clicked, why is that? note: `value="2"` is there for specific use.

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="search-form" method="get">
<input class="search-input" type="text" value="Search..." name="s" id="s" 
onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Search...'" 
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search...') this.value = ''">
<input class="submit-search" type="button" value="2">
</form>
```

Comment: Any reason not to use the `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: @toscho probably that IE < 10 doesnt support it.

Comment: You must be getting a JS error - what is it?

Comment: @vancoder no, js works fine, it's just not submitting when I click that input button, nothing happens at all

Comment: what about using `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use `<input type="submit" />` or `<button type="submit" />`.

`<input type="button" />` is valid but doesn't submit the form by default (without you adding any ajax/js magic to it.